# Noob question about Android and XmlParser

Tags: android, xml-parsing, xmlpullparser

I'm new to Android want to read a XML-file and write the content into a `ListView`

The XML Parser must be the problem. I hope it is only a little mistake in my code.

`orderxml2.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<order>
   <item id="1">
      <title>BiTest1</title>
      <group>G1</group>
      <price>5.00</price>
      <description>Example</description>
   </item>
   <item id="2">
      <title>Test2</title>
      <group>g1</group>
      <price>2.00</price>
      <description>Example</description>
   </item>
</order>
```

The Parser

```
public class Order extends Activity 
{
    private String[] lv_arr = {};
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.order);

            try {
                ArrayList<String> orderxmlarray = PrepareListFromXml();
                lv_arr = (String[]) orderxmlarray.toArray(new String[0]);
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewOrder1);

            lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Order.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lv_arr));
        }

        public ArrayList<String> PrepareListFromXml() throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
        {
            ArrayList<String> orderItems = new ArrayList<String>();
            XmlResourceParser orderxml = getResources().getXml(R.xml.orderxml2);

            orderxml.next();
            int eventType = orderxml.getEventType();

            while (eventType != XmlResourceParser.END_DOCUMENT) 
            {
                if (eventType == XmlResourceParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
                    orderItems.add(orderxml.getAttributeValue(null, "title"));                              
                }

                else if(eventType == XmlResourceParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                    orderItems.add(orderxml.getAttributeValue(null, "title"));          
                }

                try {
                    eventType = orderxml.next();
                } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return orderItems;
        }
}
```

Comment: Add a stacktrace please. @Tom Dignan i think it's the only way to teach those new users that don't even know what a stacktrace is but whatever.

Comment: orderItems.add(orderxml.getAttributeValue(null, "title"));  ---- Your XML has no "title" attributes. Did you just copy paste this?

Comment: @mibollma, I removed my comment from your answer. Do as you wish, but keep in mind how the notion of duplicate questions is frowned upon here. Should it not be the same for duplicate answers?

Comment: @Tom Dignan I don't know. That's something the community must decide i guess. I only did it on questions that can't be answered without a stacktrace anyway.

Comment: @mibollma we are the community

Comment: @Tom Dignan Sure but we can't make new rules can we... anyways ill just ignore bad questions like that in the future

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I think that the XMLParser is the problem. But what is the right syntax to read my XML file? Is getAttributeValue not the right command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My working code:

```
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {

                if (orderParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                    orderItems.add(orderParser.nextText());
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, you can visit this site http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/ . Read section Easier SAX parsing, I think that the solution presented there would be better than what you have right know, definitely less error prone.